# Spring Integration Metadatastore

Tags: spring-integration

I have added a bean called metadataStore to my spring boot + spring integration application and expected that the ftp synchronization would have been persisted and intact even after a server restart. 
Nevertheless, my early tests suggests otherwise; If I start the server and let it pick-up and process 3 tests files and then restart the server, then these same 3 files will be pick-up and processed again - as if no persistent metadataStore was defined at all.

I wonder if I am missing some configuration details when setting up the datastore...

```
@Configuration
public class MetadataStoreConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore() {
        PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
        return metadataStore;
    }
}
```

Also, I see in the spring-integration reference manual a short example on how to setup an idempotent receiver and metadata store. Is this what my implementation is lacking?

If that's it and if I have to set this up like in the example, where would I define my metadataStore.get and metadataStore.put calls? the outbound adapter I am using doesn't provide me with an expression attribute... Here is my naive and incomplete attempt at this:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundLogFile"
                                  auto-create-directory="true"
                                  directory="${sftp.local.dir}"
                                  channel="fileInboundChannel"
                                  prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="${setup.inbound.poller.rate}"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:filter id="fileFilter" input-channel="fileInboundChannel"
                output-channel="idempotentServiceChannel"
                discard-channel="fileDiscardChannel"
                expression="@metadataStore.get(payload.name) == null"/>
```

This is the outbound adapter used in the example:

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="idempotentServiceChannel" expression="@metadataStore.put(payload.name, '')"/>
```

In my ftp outbound adapter I can't insert the above expression :(

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sdkOutboundFtp"
                                      channel="idempotentServiceChannel"
                                      session-factory="ftpsCachingSessionFactory"
                                      charset="UTF-8"
                                      auto-create-directory="true"
                                      use-temporary-file-name="false"
                                      remote-file-separator="/"
                                      remote-directory-expression="${egnyte.remote.dir}"
                                      * NO EXPRESSION POSSIBLE HERE *
                                      mode="REPLACE">
    </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to move forward with this one, so I've instead attempted to use this approach https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/854516993283495e0b40 but still with no luck, when testing that one out I see the metadata-store.properties in my temp folder but it stays empty. shouldn't have some persisted info about my processed files? Anyways, i'll create a new question if I can't come to the bottom of this :)

Answer (score 5):

By default, the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` only persists the state on a normal application shutdown; it's kept in memory until then.

In 4.1.2, we changed it to implement `Flushable` so users can flush the state at any time.

Consider using an `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` in the `local-filter` on the inbound adapter instead of a separate filter element. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-inbound) for more information.

Starting with version `4.1.5` this [filter has an option `flushOnUpdate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html#x4.2-file-filter) to `flush()` the metadata store on every update.

Other metadata stores that use an external server (Redis, Mongo, Gemfire) don't need to be flushed.